# How to prevent user to select and swap images at a same time from image library so that it doesn't to go edit view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8.4

I'm having a problem regarding selecting image from image library in iPhone(iOS 8.4).

**Here is my code:**

```
   UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   imagePicker.delegate = self;
   imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
   imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
   [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

But if I select an image and swap that image at the same time it opens an edit view and then if I try to delete that image, my app crash.

Is it a default feature of image library? Or can it be handled by code?

Please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you could try

```
NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    void (^assetGroupEnumerator) (ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if(group != nil)
        {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
             {
                 //ALAssetRepresentation holds all the information about the asset being accessed.
                 if(result)
                 {
                     ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [result defaultRepresentation];

                     if (representation !=nil)
                     {
                         UIImage *PhotoThumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];
                         [fetchedThumbnails addObject:PhotoThumbnail];
                         UIImage * latestPhoto = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];
                         [fetchedImages addObject:latestPhoto];
                     }
                 }
             }];
            [assetGroups addObject:group];
        }

        galleryImagesCV.hidden=NO;
        [galleryImagesCV reloadData];
    };

    assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos;

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupTypes usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
     {
        NSLog(@"A problem occurred");
     }];
```

import AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h

That will give you all images from gallery in arrays. You can show these in a custom view and select/swap etc.

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you so much but I don't want to customise it using another view.
I'm having this error when try to delete that particular image-
Failed to save context <PLSharedManagedObjectContext: 0x16512ed0>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134030.)" (null) (null)

Comment: You are deleting image from Library with Obj-C code?

Comment: yeah I found that bug last night.
I open UIImagePickerController for selecting image from library and if I select that image and suddenly swap that image at the same time, the image opens in edit view (that feature is inbuilt in iOS) but I don't want that feature in my scenario because if I delete that image from that screen, my app crash.
I have gone through this link-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270714/why-would-app-try-to-save-to-plsharedmanagedobjectcontext 
But nothing gonna happens in my case.

Comment: Can you detail me what do you mean by swap? How are you swapping the image

Comment: swapping means select a image by one finger and then try to swap it right or left with another finger then it goes that edit view.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the same?